# Need to add data to CSV without adding comma to data

Tags: csv, go

I have a bunch of either IP ranges or single addresses. I figured out how to loop through them, I can successfully print them to the console. However, when i write the same data to CSV, it magically adds a comma after every value (instead of adding them all under the same header separated by a space). I'm following all the rules (well, seemingly, anyway) to appending data in Go, but i just can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm assuming the CSV function in Go just see's a space and thinks it should be separated by a comma.

The `input` part of this is looping through addresses that are `[]string` types. So one value could be `127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.255` or just `127.0.0.1`. I just want them to look like this in the csv column `Included`: `127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.255 127.0.0.1`

Screenshot of how the data appears in the console (correct): 
[image]

Screenshot of the CSV (not correct): 
[image]

I want the example CSV to look like this:

[image]

Here is the code i'm working with right now. If more is needed, let me know, but this is how i'm writing the data to CSV.

```
func ToCsv(inputs []interface{}, output io.Writer) {
    w := csv.NewWriter(output)
    defer w.Flush()

    if len(inputs) == 0 {
        return
    } else {
        // Get Header
        r := reflect.ValueOf(inputs[0])
        val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(inputs[0]))
        var headers []string
        for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
            headers = append(headers, val.Type().Field(i).Name)
        }
        w.Write(headers)


        // Get Content
        for _, input := range inputs {
            ri := reflect.ValueOf(input)
            var result []string
            for i := 0; i < ri.NumField(); i++ {
                switch ri.Field(i).Interface().(type) {
                case []string:
                    //this is the part that's looping through all the ip addresses and is causing me a headache
                    stringArray := ri.Field(i).Interface().([]string)
                    for ii := 0; ii < len(stringArray); ii++ {
                        stringArray[ii] = strings.Replace(stringArray[ii], " ", ":", -1)
                        result = append(result,stringArray[ii])
                    }
                case bool:
                    result = append(result, strconv.FormatBool(ri.Field(i).Interface().(bool)))
                case int32:
                    result = append(result, strconv.FormatInt(int64(ri.Field(i).Interface().(int32)), 10))
                case []int32:
                    intArray := ri.Field(i).Interface().([]int32)
                    for ii := 0; ii < len(intArray); ii++ {
                        result = append(result, strconv.FormatInt(int64(intArray[ii]),10))
                    }
                case string:
                    result = append(result, ri.Field(i).Interface().(string))
                default:
                    result = append(result, "")
                }
            }
            w.Write(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need  to add ip address as list to the , but you are directly appending it to result variable

Comment: Can you explain a little further on this? What can i do other than appending it directly to result?

Comment: why were you using reflection?

Comment: Because i'm a total novice with Go, sadly. This is my first foray into compiled programming languages. I usually stick with powershell/python, and even then i'm pretty terrible

Comment: It's not suggested to use reflection, though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? You say it's not suggested, but what would i use in it's place?

Comment: why can't you pass type `[]string` data in the first place, by converting type `x` into `string` type where ever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to get the output of data without comma,
csv reader has a variable known as, `Comma`, which sets the byte which separates values in csv.

The same goes for both csv reader and writer.

For csv data with other than comma, you need to set `Comma` variable of reader or writer respectively.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    // temporary csv
    sr := strings.NewReader(
        `"name" "value"
"nilsocket" "7"
"nil" "77"
`)

    // set your src of csv
    r := csv.NewReader(sr)

    r.Comma = ' '         // set this if your values were seperated
    // with anything other than ','(comma)

    res, _ := r.ReadAll() // read csv, res is going to be [][]string type
    // you can fetch one record with r.Read()
    // don't forget to check for errors

    w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout) // set your dst for csv

    w.Comma = ' '                // set the Comma byte to space

    w.WriteAll(res) // write csv

    w.Flush()       // don't forget to flush
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer.  As it stands, this answer barely educates the asker, let alone future visitors.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark there is nothing to explain, code speaks for itself and comments do that too, but I will add some more information.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't immediately notice the comments in your code.  Nonetheless, it's always nice to include a brief overview of what the issue was with the original code at the top!

Comment: Would'nt setting the comma variable add a comma everywhere a space exists? Some of the data for the other fields have spaces. Or is this completely wrong thinking? I will try working on this tonight

Comment: @nilsocket this didn't work. now all of my data is in the first column

Comment: @nilsocket I need each value under it's proper header, and under the `included` header i need all the ip addresses under it, separated by a space

Comment: @JamesonParker are your fields all in one line, are you reading input from file or you are the one who generates it.

Comment: I'm the one generated the data i'm throwing in the CSV using a swagger-codegen client. The individual values get appended to the result variable

Comment: @instead of appending everything to result, make result as `[][]string`, and append `[]string` to result, then you can simply pass it to csv writer.